# Chromeless YouTube API Displaying Overlay Play Button

Tags: actionscript-3, youtube-api

All of a sudden the chromeless YouTube API is displaying the native overlay play button.

This is reproducible on the YouTube Demo page (https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo, set type to display an AS3 chromeless player).

Is anyone else experiencing this?

Answer (score 0):

I am also experiencing strange behavior while setting dimensions of the player, and modestbranding logo is sometimes completely out of the video area. This is happening since yesterday, before that it was jsut fine

Did they changed something in the API? Anyone else experiencing problems as well?

Comment: I am suddenly having a great number of problems that seems to be from the overlays. Player resizes when overlay appears and problems seem to accumulate so that each video is worse than the last. After a while videos are very oversized, wrong aspect ratio, black borders underneath YT logo, ads cause security errors when I click the x to close them and more. Seems like another undocumented change.